# How to do counts on 2 fields and then get a difference

Tags: sql

```
Select count(*) from column_alerts
Select count(*) from column_alerts where publish_datetime > (sysdate - (2/24/60))
```

Show the difference of column_alerts - (records addded after 2 mins)

thanks

Comment: Which database ? you can use `minus` keyword in between putting everything inside a bracket .

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(*) - sum(case when publish_datetime >(sysdate - (2/24/60)) then 1 else 0 end) from column_alerts
```

Comment: Select count(*) / (count(*)- sum(case when publish_datetime <(sysdate - (2/24/60)))from column_alerts                                               ---- trying to find percentage difference or change... am I missing ()??

Comment: select count(*) / (count(*)- sum(case when publish_datetime < (sysdate - (2/24/60)) then 1 else 0 end)) from column_alerts